# Running a Visual Basic Form on SharePoint 2010?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, form

I am currently using SharePoint 2010 Foundation, I am also using Visual Basic 2010. I want to take a form I recently created in VB and display it in SharePoint for my users to access. I do not want everyone to have to install VB to run the program, and since everyone already uses SP2010 to collaborate, I want them just to go to the page or web part and run this program. Is this something I can do and if so please tell me how.

Thanks,
Colby

Comment: Is this a "Windows Forms" VB executable? You really need to provide more details regarding what the application does and how it is constructed before we could suggest anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Citirx and connected it to the webfront of my SharePoint page, which ran the .exe of my VB FORM whenever a user selected the link.

Answer (score 1):

I would not see this possible as most like your VB end-result is and EXE which just per-se is not possible to upload in SharePoint libraries as it by default a restricted extension in SP-CA. So besides the fact that is totally against what collaboration is meant for, but even so, it is a desktop application by definition, and even if you somehow bypass that security boundary, it would simply result in people having to download the application and run-it locally - e.g. cannot run in the context of SharePoint.

So you could either envision to re-build using a web-technology, e.g. even a Access web database could get you closer, but rather built your own Web Part using data stored in SharePoint lists.